# Wrapping byte array in ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I am just trying to understand the wrapping of an array of bytes using ByteArrayInputStream class. Here is the code that I have doubt about it.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

//write data into byte array...

InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

//read first byte
int data = input.read();
while(data != -1) {
    //do something with data

    //read next byte
    data = input.read();
}
```

My question is it it possible to write this part

`InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);`

like this

`ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);`

And why the author of this code created the object with both the super and sub classes?

I really thank you for your help.

Comment: `InputStream input` is not an object, it is a reference to an object which must implement this interface.  Note: you can't create an instance of InputStream.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

like

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

It is functionally the same.

However, in OOP it's widely recommended to "program to interfaces". See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) for an explanation.

In this case, strictly speaking, `InputStream` is not an interface, but an abstract superclass. However, it more or less *acts like* an interface.

Answer (score 0):

> is it it possible to write this part

```
(InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);)
```

> like this

```
    ( ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);)
```

Certainly. Why do you think otherwise? What happened when you tried it? Why are you using StackOverflow as a substitute for conclusive experiments?

> And why the author of this code created the object with both the super and sub classes?

He didn't. He created the object as an instance of `ByteArrayInputStream`. He then assigned the result to a variable of type `InputStream`. It's perfectly normal.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I was not experimenting here. I'm looking for help to understand the concept. I think that is the purpose of the site right?

Comment: @TabTab What is often baffling for experienced developers is why people ask questions which is surely easier to work out for yourself.